# Graphing a dataset

Tags: javascript

What type of graphical tool shows the shape of the data set by stacking x's above each data value on q number line?

Comment: Are you referring to an "X Stack Q" graph?

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing much detail of what the dataset looks like, so specific advice is hard to give.  However, you might find a solution for your graphing needs with [Google Visualizations](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html)